# Can I Hide the tax line on my PDF invoice (woocommerce) for a specific country?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, woocommerce, invoice

I have tried to address the problem like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rate_label', 'custom_tax_rate_label', 10, 2 );
function custom_tax_rate_label( $rate_name, $key ){
    return '';
}
```

But this only hides the tax label on checkout. I need the label to be hidden in invoice PDF.[Invoice Label (between green frame: inkl. 14.00$ Mwst. AT 20%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjCCA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. First I created custom action in themes>current theme> functions.php like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_mail_without_mail', 'woocommerce_mail_without_mail');
 public function dokan_mail_without_mail( $values ) {
  $without_tax=explode('(',$values);
  echo count($without_tax)>0 ? wp_kses_post($without_tax[0] ): 
   wp_kses_post($values);
   }
```

And add custom action to wp-content>plugins>woocommerce>templates>emails>email-order-details.php(or other email templates but templates have to have $total['value'] code partical  ) line 72 like this:

```
<?php  do_action('dokan_mail_without_mail',$total['value']) ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

than put condition on invoice file so it will be stay hidden.